# unable to insert into mysql table's timestamp column via Presto connector

Tags: mysql, presto

I've created a test mysql table with timestamp column. When I'm trying to insert data via Presto. Presto fails.

In Presto 0.229 CLI:
*insert into test(id,Date,timestamp) values(6,current_date,localtimestamp);*

The result:
*Query 20191204_051244_00031_xrwc9 failed: Unsupported column type: timestamp*

The MYSQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `NewTable` (
`ID`  int(11) NOT NULL ,
`var`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT '' ,
`Date`  date NULL DEFAULT '' ,
`Time`  time NULL DEFAULT '' ,
`Timestamp`  timestamp NULL DEFAULT '' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
;
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented support for `timestamp` data type in MySQL connector around Presto 312.

[Download latest Presto](https://prestosql.io/download.html) 326 and enjoy.

Alternatively, download [Starburst Presto](https://www.starburstdata.com/starburst-presto-sql/) and enjoy some additional benefits as well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot default `date` or `time` data types with empty values.

```
CREATE TABLE `NewTable` (
`ID`  int(11) NOT NULL ,
`var`  varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL DEFAULT '' ,
`Date`  date NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`Time`  time NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`Timestamp`  timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
;
```